# Study error message : Quantity for entry order must be possitive, value enter is -834444.22394394

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

Hi stackoverflow community.

Need help on this error message. I don't understand how my entry value can be negative my initial capital is set to 1000. Please see the details below

```
strategy(" STOCH RSI Call-outs Multi-resolution", overlay=true, pyramiding=2, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.07, default_qty_type=strategy.cash, initial_capital=100, slippage=2, precision=0)

// Risk management
multiplier = input(3.5, "SL Mutiplier", minval=1, step=0.1)
ATR_period = input(6,"ATR period", minval=1, step=1)
RiskPercent = input(0.06, title="Max Risk Percent", type=input.float, minval=0.01, step=0.01)

// Strategy
long_signal = crossover(k,d) and crossover(k2,d2) and crossover(k3,d3) 
entry_long = long_signal
entry_price_long =valuewhen(entry_long,close,0)
SL_floating_long = entry_price_long - multiplier*Atr(ATR_period)
exit_long = close < SL_floating_long 
exit_long2 = crossunder(k,d) and crossunder(k2,d2) and crossunder(k3,d3)
DrawDwn= input(30,title="Max Drawdow Percentage",minval=1,step=0.1)
strategy.risk.max_drawdown(value=DrawDwn, type=strategy.percent_of_equity)
MaxPositionRisk =  strategy.equity * RiskPercent
size = MaxPositionRisk

//Back test period
timeInRange() =>
    time > timestamp(syminfo.timezone,fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay, 00, 00) and time < timestamp(syminfo.timezone, toYear, toMonth, toDay, 23, 59) ? true : false

if timeInRange()
    strategy.entry("long",long=true,qty=size, comment="Insert Enter Long Comment",when=entry_long)
    strategy.exit("TP1","long", qty_percent=long_tp1_qty, limit=long_take_level_1)//, trail_points=entry_price_long * long_trailing / syminfo.mintick, trail_offset=entry_price_long * long_trailing / syminfo.mintick)
    strategy.exit("TP2", qty_percent=long_tp2_qty, limit=long_take_level_2) //, trail_points=entry_price_long * long_trailing / syminfo.mintick, trail_offset=entry_price_long * long_trailing / syminfo.mintick)
    strategy.close(id="long", when=exit_long, comment="Exit Long")
    strategy.close(id="long",when=exit_long2,comment="")
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the entry is causing this error? Where is long_tp1_quantity calculated?

Add  at the bottom of your script:
`plotchar(size, 'Size','')`
`plotchar(long_tp1_qty', 'TP1','')`
`plotchar(long_tp2_qty', 'TP2','')`

Then comment out the strategy section and check the data window for these values.

Comment: @bajaco thanks for helping out.  here is the missing part below. Meanwhile i''ll plot it just as said. cheers

Comment: // TAKE PROFIT AND STOP LOSS
long_tp1_inp = input(2, title='Long Take Profit 1 %', step=0.1)/100
long_tp1_qty = input(10, title="Long Take Profit 1 Qty", step=1)

long_tp2_inp = input(5, title='Long Take Profit 2%', step=0.1)/100
long_tp2_qty = input(50, title="Long Take Profit 2 Qty", step=1)

long_take_level_1 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + long_tp1_inp)
long_take_level_2 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + long_tp2_inp)

Comment: @hajaco i have plotted the variable as advised it doesn't return no value

Comment: Then there is some sort of problem in your calculation of that value. If a value used to create that value is na at some point, that could cause it. Plot all of the variables used to create your variable independently.